# $ (a_n) $ is a sequence s.t. its partial limits are $ 3 , - 1 $. Define $ b_n = | a_n - 1 | $. Show $ b_n \rightarrow 2 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Problem:** Let $ (a_n) $ be a sequence s.t. its partial limits are **only** from the set  $ \{ 3 , - 1 \} $ ( infinite limits are not allowed to be partial limits of $ (a_n) $ ). Define a new sequence $ b_n = | a_n - 1 | $. Show that $ b_n \rightarrow 2 $.

**Attempt:** Suppose that $ b_n \nrightarrow 2 $. Meaning there exists $ \epsilon>0 $ s.t. $ \forall N \in \mathbb{N} . \exists n^*>N.| |a_n - 1 | - 2 | \geq \epsilon  $.
Choose $ N=1 $, then there exists  $ n^* > N $ s.t.  $ | |a_n^* - 1 | - 2 | \geq \epsilon \iff | |a_n^* - 1 | - 2 | \geq \epsilon \iff  |a_n^* - 1 | - 2  \geq \epsilon$ or $ |a_n^* - 1 | - 2  \leq - \epsilon $.
[ I am stuck. I don't see how I can continue if I assume wlog either $ |a_n^* - 1 | - 2  \geq \epsilon $ or $ |a_n^* - 1 | - 2  \leq - \epsilon $, I think a better option would be If I wouldn't  try to prove by contradiction, but that attempt was failure for me as well ].

Do you have any ideas how I should continue? or if I don't choose to prove by contradiction, how would one proceed after taking arbitrary $ \epsilon > 0 $ and using the givens that $3 ,-1  $ are partial limits?

**Edit**: The teacher-assistant told me that the theorem is true.

Comment: Are $\pm\infty$ allowed as "partial limits"? If not this is false (consider the sequence $3, -1, 1, 3, -1, 2, 3, -1, 3\dots$.)

Comment: You are right, I edited the question so that the only partial limits are 3 and -1. If so then the sequence $ (a_n) $ is bounded. But how does this help me?

Comment: Adding the word **only** does not clarify whether you're allowing infinite "partial limits".

Comment: I'm not allowing infinite partial limits.

Comment: Then  you should really say so in the question.

Comment: what is a partial limit? The limit of a subsequence?

Comment: @Snoop Exactly.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 you should be more specific with the partial limits assumption. Do you assume that all *convergent* subsequences  of $a_n$ have just two limit points?

Comment: @Snoop Yes, and those two limit points are : $ 3 , -1 $.  That is how the original question appears but only after looking at the answer I could solve the ambiguities of the question.

Comment: I don't think the question is ambiguous if partial limits are defined in $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since there are no infinite partial, or sub-sequential limits, then $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.

We claim that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have  $|a_n-(-1)|<\varepsilon$ or $|a_n-3|<\varepsilon$.

Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists an $n\geq N$ with $|a_{n}-(-1)|\geq\varepsilon$ and $|a_{n}-3|\geq\varepsilon$. After possibly permuting or re-ordering terms, this gives rise to a sub-sequence $\left(a_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Since this sub-sequence $\left(a_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, then by Bolzano-Wierstrass, there is a convergent sub-sequence of it, which is a partial limit of $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. This new partial limit cannot be $-1$ or $3$, which is a contradiction, thus the claim holds.

Define the sequence $b_n=|a_n-1|$. We want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=2$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n-(-1)|<\varepsilon$ or $|a_n-3|<\varepsilon$.

Let $n\geq N$. Now, there are two cases: $a_n-1\geq 0$ or $a_n-1<0$. In the former case, we have that $$|b_n-2|=||a_n-1|-2|=|a_n-3|$$
In the latter case, we have that $$|b_n-2|=||a_n-1|-2|=|-a_n-1|=|a_n-(-1)|$$
Now $|b_n-2|<\varepsilon$, thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=2$.

**Edit 2:** To make the cases more clear, picking up from "We want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=2$", this is equivalent to showing that for all $n\geq N$, we have $$||a_n-1|-2|<\varepsilon\Longleftrightarrow-\varepsilon<|a_n-1|-2<\varepsilon \Longleftrightarrow 2-\varepsilon < |a_n-1|<2+\varepsilon$$

In the case where $a_n-1\geq 0$, we have
$$3-\varepsilon <a_n< 3+\varepsilon\Longrightarrow |a_n-3|<\varepsilon$$
The case when $a_n-1<0$ is similar.

**Edit 1:** I did not read the comments and I misinterpreted the statement of the question previously which lead to the answer below.

I think this statement is false. Consider the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined as

$$\begin{cases}
n &\text{ if }n\equiv 1\mod 3\\
-1&\text{ if }n\equiv 2\mod 3\\
3&\text{ if }n\equiv 0\mod 3
\end{cases} $$

The only finite, partial limits of $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are $-1$ and $3$.

The sequence $b_n=|a_n-1|$ is seen to be
$$b_n = 
\begin{cases}
n-1 &\text{ if } n\equiv 1\mod 3\\
2 &\text{ if else }
\end{cases}$$
but $\left(b_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge, since $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(b_n)=\infty$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}(b_n)=2$.

Comment: $a_{3k + 1} \to \infty$ and that's not allowed as the OP clarified.

Comment: I don't understand the line:" there are two cases, $ |a_n-1|\geq 0 $ or $ |a_n-1|<0 $ ". Where do we derive those cases from?.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 I just edited. The $|a_n-1|<0$ didn't even make sense. You derive those cases because we want to look at $|b_n-2|=||a_n-1|-2|$. There are two cases: $a_n-1\geq 0$ or $a_n-1<0$ for some fixed $n\geq N$.

Comment: I see, but from where do we derive those cases ?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Ok I think I understand. I thought you are deriving the cases from the statement $ \forall n \geq N. |a_n-(-1)|<\varepsilon \lor |a_n-3|<\varepsilon  $. But now I see that you are simply just considering these two cases since you took  an arbitrary $ n  \geq N$ ( without any connection to previous statements).

Comment: @hazelnut_116 I will edit this answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 is it more clear now?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 If you are familiar with $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ then this is a property of those.

Comment: @CSquared Yes!, by the way, how did you figure out the proof for this?. It looks similar to the answer the teacher-assistant gave me ( but only that his answer is scrambled and not understandable at all )

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes, although I didn't notice that until you told me.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 after playing around with it a little bit, I noticed that the sequence had to be bounded. Then, if there were anything else that $a_n$ was close to besides $-1$ and $3$ for large $n$, it would have to be a limit point, as the sequence is bounded.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 sorry to bother, but we do need to show that $|a_n-3|<\varepsilon$ implies $a_n-1\geq 0$ as well. This can be seen from considering cases when $a_n-3\geq 0$ or $a_n-3<0$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. For example, if $a_n-3\geq 0$, then $\varepsilon+2>a_n-1\geq 2\geq 2-\varepsilon$ so $a_n-1>0$. If $a_n-1<0$, then we get $0<2-\varepsilon<a_n-1<2<2+\varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon$. similarly for $|a_n-(-1)|<\varepsilon$ implies $a_n-1<0$.

Comment: @CSquared I think considering the cases  $ a_n−1 \geq 0 $  or $ a_n−1<0 $  are enough because we get the proper $ \epsilon $ inequalities which show $ b_n \rightarrow  2$ . I'm not sure I understand why we need to consider the implication you talk about