# Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers that has 2 partial limits: $2$ and $-1$. Define $b_n = \frac{2a_n^2-a_n-1}{a_n^2+1}$. Prove $b_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers that only has 2 partial limits: $2$ and $-1$.
Define $b_n = \frac{2a_n^2-a_n-1}{a_n^2+1}$.

Prove $b_n$ converges.

It is obvious to me that if we plug in the partial limits of $a_n$ into $b_n$ we get $1$, but how do we prove $b_n$ doesn't actually have more partial limits other than $1$?

Comment: Does your definition of „partial limit“ allow $\pm\infty$?

Comment: Yes. It does allow it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$ (a_n) $ is a sequence s.t. its partial limits are $ 3 , - 1 $. Define $ b_n = | a_n - 1 | $. Show $ b_n \rightarrow 2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115664/a-n-is-a-sequence-s-t-its-partial-limits-are-3-1-define-b-n) (the sequences are different but the methods are the same)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ |b_n-1|=\bigg|\frac{a_n^2-a_n-2}{a_n^2+1}\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{(a_n-2)(a_n+1)}{a_n^2+1}\bigg|\le|(a_n-2)(a_n+1)| $$
and $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.